# How can I change the color of one letter in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a string and I want to change just one color letter in JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<div id="lettersList">Hello</div>
```

In my JavaScript file, I retrieve like this (normal)

```
var lettres = document.getElementById("lettersList");
```

But I don't know how to change the color of just one word (the 'o' of "hello" for example).
If I change thanks to

`for (var i=0; i<lettres.length; i++ { lettres[i].style.color = "yellow"; }`

it changes all the text (of course). But I don't want that.

Comment: `it changes all the text(of course)` are you sure ????

Comment: yes, i'm sure ;)

Comment: `lettres.length`  and `lettres[i]` would be undefined :)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method on the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property of the element:

```js
const element = document.querySelector('#lettersList');
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace('o', '<span style="color: red;">o</span>');
```

```html
<div id="lettersList">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code :

```
 var letters = document.getElementById()
```

you actually retrieve the whole element, not the text in it. That might be the reason that it changed its color totally.

So I suggest you to use

```
document.getElementById().innerHtml()
```

. 
This function will retrieve the content in your HTML tags (div). Then you do the color changing like

```
for(var i = 0; i<letters.length; i++){
    //only change the one you want to
    if(i == 4 // or whatever you like){
        element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(letters[i], '<span style="color: yellow;">'+letters[i]+'</span>');
    }
}
```

Comment: @SarahB because It colors the letter according to its position in that word. The if condition is set to find a letter with specific position（4th？ 5th？ of the word） To color all letter in a word you will need to change the if condition to if（letter[i] == "o"//or any other letter you need to color) then do color changing.

Comment: er， I just realized that this is a bad solution. You should use str.replace（）directly，to apply color changing to all letters in that word you will need str.replace(/o/g, '<span...................</span>')  It will find all 'o' in the word and replace them with content in' ', no more for(){} or if condition. Just as Micheal suggests in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

it works with

```
for(var i = 0; i<letters.length; i++){ if(i == 4 { element.innerHTML =element.innerHTML.replace(letters[i], '<span style="color:yellow;">'+letters[i]+'</span>');}}
```

But if a word contains two similar letters, I can't color the both... Why that ?

Answer (score 0):

if a word contains two similar letters then with the for loop we can use position of letter as `i` inside
`if i == n , replace(letter[n], styled span tag)`